# CQRS + Microservices: How to handle relations / validation?

Tags: validation, relationship, one-to-many, microservices, cqrs

**Scenario:**

- I have 2 Microservices (which both use CQRS + Event Sourcing internally)
- Microservice 1 manages Contacts (= Aggregate Root)
- Microservice 2 manages Invoices (= Aggregate Root)

The recipient of an invoice must be a valid contact.

**CreateInvoiceCommand:**

```
{
  "content": "my invoice content",
  "recipient": "42"
}
```

---

I now read lot's of times, that the write side (= the command handler) shouldn't call the read side.

---

Taking this into account, the Invoices Microservice must listen to all `ContactCreated` and `ContactDeleted` events in order to know if the given recipient id is valid.

Then I'd have thousands of Contacts within the Invoices Microservice, even if I know that only a few of them will ever receive an Invoice.

---

Is there any best practice to handle those scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The recipient of an invoice must be a valid contact.

So the first thing you need to be aware of - if two entities are part of different aggregates, you can't really implement "apply a change to this entity only if *that* entity satisfies a specification", because *that* entity could change between the moment you evaluate the specification and the moment you perform the write.

In other words - you can only get *eventual* consistency across an aggregate boundary.

The aggregate is the authority for its own state, but everything else (for example, the contents of the command message), it pretty much has to accept that some external authority has checked the data.

There are a couple approaches you can take here

1) You can blindly accept that the recipient specified in the command is valid.

2) You can try to verify the validity of the recipient from some external authority (aka: a read model of some other aggregate) between *receiving* it from the untrusted source and submitting it to the domain model.

3) You can blindly accept the command as described, but treat the invoice as provisional until the validity of the recipient is confirmed.  That means there is a second command to run on the invoice that certifies the recipient.

Note - from the point of view of the model, these different commands are equivalent, but at the application layer they don't need to be -- you can restrict access to the command to trusted sources (don't make it part of the public api, require authorization that is only available to trusted sources, etc).

Approach #3 is the most microservicy, as the two commands can be separated in time -- you can accept the CreateInvoice command as soon as it arrives, and certify the recipient asynchronously.

> Where would you put approach 4), where the Invoices Microservice has it's own Contacts Store which gets updated whenever there's a ContactCreated or ContactDeleted event? Then both entities are part of the same service and boundary. Now it should be possible to make things consistent, right?

No.  You've made the two entities part of the same service, but the problem was never that they were in different *services*, but that they are in separate *aggregates* -- meaning we can be changing the entity states concurrently, which means that we can't ensure that they are immediately synchronized.

If you wanted immediate consistency, you need a model that draws your boundaries differently.

For instance, if the invoice entities were modeled as part of the Contacts aggregate, then the aggregate can ensure the invariant that new invoices require a valid recipient -- the domain model uses the copy of the state in memory to confirm that the recipient *was* valid when we loaded, and the write into the book of record verifies that the book of record hadn't changed since the load happened.

The write of the aggregate state is a compare-and-swap in the book of record; if some concurrent process had invalidated the recipient, the CAS operation would fail.

The trade off, of course, is that *any* change to the Contact aggregate would also cause the invoice to fail; concurrent editing of different invoices with the same recipient goes out the window.

Aggregates are all or nothing; they aren't separable.

Now, one out might be that your Invoice aggregate has a part that must be immediately consistent with the recipient, and another part where eventually consistent, or even inconsistent, is acceptable.  In which case your goal is to refactor the model.

Comment: Thank you! Where would you put **approach 4)**, where the Invoices Microservice has it's own Contacts Store which gets updated whenever there's a `ContactCreated` or `ContactDeleted` event? Then both entities are part of the same service and boundary. Now it should be possible to make things consistent, right? (Except when the command contains a newly created Contact, but the Invoices Microservice hasn't yet processed the `ContactCreated` event - this makes things eventually consistent, too?!)

Answer (score 3):

> The recipient of an invoice must be a valid contact.

This is a business rule. The question should be asked, what does this business rule mean for my application? Who should take responsibility for implementing this rule, or can the responsibility be shared?

One possibility is that, yes, the business rule is about invoices so it should be the responsibility of the Invoices Service to implement it.

However, the business rule is really about the creation of invoices. And the owner of invoice creation in your architecture is, strangely, not the Invoices Service. The reason for this is that the name of the command is `CreateInvoiceCommand`.

Let's think about this - the Invoices Service will never just create an invoice on its own. It just provides the capability. In this architecture, the actual owner of invoice creation is the sender of the command.

Using this line of reasoning, if the business rule is saying that invoice creation cannot happen against an invalid recipient, then it becomes the responsibility of the command sender to ensure this business rule is implemented.

This would be a very different scenario if, rather than receiving a command, the Invoices Service subscribed to events. As an example, an event called `WidgetSold`. In this scenario, the owner of invoice creation clearly would be the Invoicing service, and so the business rule would be implemented there instead.

> If the user clicks the create invoice for contact 42 button, it's the
>   user's responsibility to take care that contact 42 exists

Yes, that is correct. The user's intention is to create an invoice. The business rules around invoice creation should, therefore, be enforced at this point. How this happens (or whether this happens at all) is a different question.

> But what if the user doesn't care? Then it would create an invoice
>   with an invalid recipient id.

Also correct. As you say, there are side-effects to this approach, one of which is that you can end up with inconsistent data across your system. That is one of the realities of SOA.

> Isn't this somehow similar to this: The Invoice has a currencyCode
>   property, it's a String.

I don't know if I agree or not. Is asking *is this a valid ISO currency?* different to asking *is entity 42 valid according to another system?*. I would think so.

> Isn't it kinda the same as *given recipient is not null and is valid
>   according to my Contacts Database?*

I agree that in reality, you could implement this validation in the service. I am just saying that I don't think it's the right place for it. If you wanted to do this, you would have to either call out the another service or store all contacts locally, as you framed your question originally. I think it's simpler to just do it outside of the service.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds quite interesting and reasonable. Let me summarize and see if I really got your point: If the user clicks the *create invoice for `contact 42`* button, it's the user's responsibility to take care that `contact 42` exists. Seems pretty straight forward. **But** what if the user doesn't care? Then it would create an invoice with an invalid recipient id. Means: I have garbage within my database. Is it bad? Yes, but only in term's of free disk space. But it won't cause any trouble for the application itself, because it's just an orphaned piece of data.

Comment: Okay. The (hopefully) only thing I still don't understand is: Why is *valid contact* a business rule and shouldn't be part of the Invoice's CommandHandler? Isn't this somehow similar to this: The Invoice has a `currencyCode` property, it's a String. In my opinion the CommandHandler will now validate that the provided `currencyCode` is not null and is valid according to ISO 4217. Isn't it kinda the same as *given recipient is not null and is valid according to my Contacts Database*? Maybe I'm completely wrong. Please enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer depends on how resilient you want the system to be, that is, how to handle the situation in wich the `Contacts Microservice` is down (not responding or very slow).

**1. You want to be very resilient**

If the `Contacts Microservice` is down, you want to be able to emit invoices for some (maybe most) of the contacts. In this case you listen to the `ContactCreated` and `ContactDeleted` and maintain a (eventually consistent) local list of *valid* contacts; they should be named accordingly to the Ubiquitous language in this bounded context, like `Payers` (or something like that). Then, in the Application layer, when building the `CreateInvoiceCommand` you check that `Payer` is valid and create the command.

**2. You don't need to be resilient**

If the `Contacts Microservice` is down, you refuse to generate invoices. In this case, when building the command you make a request to the `Invoices Microservice` API endpoint and verify that the `Payer` is valid.

In any case, you check for contact's validity before the command is dispatched.

Comment: Thanks you. Your first point sounds like *it's allowed to call the read side from within the write side*. But I read everywhere that it should be avoided. Or did they just man that you shouldn't call your own read side? (i.e. InvoiceCommandHandler shouldn't execute an InvoiceQuery)? ... And why check the validity *before* the command is dispatched? I thought validation should be part of the Command Handler?

Comment: You check before because the Aggregate can not query outside services. The Aggregate must enforce invariants based only on previous events and current command. It should be pure.

Comment: I know that the aggregate can't do this. But from my understanding the flow is like this: `1.` Command -> CommandHandler, `2.` CommandHandler validates Command, `3.` CommandHandler modifies Aggregate (by calling methods on the Aggregate), `4.` Aggregate publishes Events, etc. . ... That's why I thought, that the Command Handler should check if the given Contact ID is valid. And afterwards it will start the Aggregate modification. So the Aggregate won't do any queries. The Command Handler does. ... But maybe I'm confused, because I read millions of CQRS articles the last days.

Comment: @BenjaminM There are at least two styles: [1].The `command` is send directly to the `Aggregate` by a `Application service`, so the `command handler` is a method on the Aggregate (my preferred style, see http://cqrs.nu/tutorial ) and [2]. The `command handler` is an `Application service` and it calls a method on the Aggregate. In both cases my opinion is that that verification is done in the `Application service` so that the `Aggregate` remains pure.

Comment: Ahh.. okay. I did only know about Style [2]. Thank you! For Style [2] you say *"the command handler is an application service"* and *"verification is done in the application service"*. So am I correct that I can do verfication within the command handler if I use style [2]? That validation shouldn't happen within the Aggregate is clear to me.

Comment: @BenjaminM That is my opinion. I like to keep the domain code as pure as possible. That makes it very testable. Also if you use style [1] you could test the `Aggregate` very nice using Behavior Driven Design: scenario.given(SomePriorEvents).when(TheCommand).then(TheResultingEvents)